# Embed HTML around selection w/o jQuery

Tags: javascript

This must be a fairly straight-forward question, but I simply need a concise way to embed HTML around a given selection of text (think: text editor) without jQuery.

The code below works fine insofar as it embeds the HTML, but it does so as a string which is obviously an issue.

Another issue with the `replace` method is that it will only replace the first instance, which will cause problems if the user has selected a single character or common combinations of letters and words.

```
    const userInput = document.getElementById('user-input'),
          embolden = document.getElementById('controls-embolden')
    let   sel

    userInput.onmouseup = function(){
      if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection().toString()
        embolden.onclick = function(){
          const txt = userInput.innerHTML
          const newTxt = txt.replace(sel, '[b]'+sel+'[/b]')
          userInput.innerHTML = newTxt
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried using `createRange`, but this will not work due in part to how I have laid out my HTML.

```
    <body>
      <div id="controls">
        <div class="controls" id="controls-embolden">Embolden</div>
      </div>
      <div id="user-input" contenteditable="true">
        # random text from an article on medium
        By portraying me in a sexual way to attendees, this would have opened the door to additional harassment, and added yet another hurdle I’d have to overcome in order to be perceived as a competent professional. The fact that nowhere along the way did ReactiveConf organizers recognize how this gift could actually be harmful, to me, demonstrated a complete lack of empathy for women in tech. That’s not an organization I want to associate myself or my employer, Meteor Development Group (MDG), with. Not only is the photo itself problematic, but also the fact that ReactiveConf never asked for my consent. I was never informed that ReactiveConf was planning on altering my photo for the event, nor did I see the superhero picture until after day one of the conference had ended. None of the organizers explicitly asked for my permission to display the picture on the big screen. Had I presented my talk on day 1, I would have been completely blindsided as I walked on stage, which is what happened to a colleague of mine who was also unhappy with his picture. Speaking at a conference is already a monumental investment of mental, emotional, and physical effort, right up until the plane ride home. The will to continue investing any more energy into an event whose organizers had showed so little consideration for their speakers vanished as soon as I received the gift. After consulting with trusted members of my team, I decided to withdraw and leave the situation immediately. By portraying me in a sexual way to attendees, this would have opened the door to additional harassment, and added yet another hurdle I’d have to overcome in order to be perceived as a competent professional. The fact that nowhere along the way did ReactiveConf organizers recognize how this gift could actually be harmful, to me, demonstrated a complete lack of empathy for women in tech. That’s not an organization I want to associate myself or my employer, Meteor Development Group (MDG), with.
      </div>
    </body>
```

I am stuck for ideas. How would one go about achieving this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthony, I guess you need to use angular brackets instead of square brackets where you are trying to apply the bold tag.

i.e instead of

```
const newTxt = txt.replace(sel, '[b]'+sel+'[/b]')
```

use

```
const newTxt = txt.replace(sel, '<b>'+sel+'</b>')
```

Comment: oh, yeah, stupid me. not sure why i was using square brackets -.-a